# Update hibernate entity outside transactional method

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-transactions

This code is causing the following error:

*optimistic locking failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect)*

I don't understand why, shouldn't be legit to update an attached entity after saving it?

```
@Service
class ServiceA {
    @Autowired
    ServiceB serviceB;
  
    @Transactional
    private void methodA() {
        MyEntity myEntity = serviceB.methodB();
        
        myEntity.setName("Alice");  
    }
}

@Service
class ServiceB {
    @Autowired
    Repository repo;
  
    @Transactional
    private MyEntity methodB() {
        MyEntity myEntity = new MyEntity();
        myEntity.setId(1L);
        myEntity.setName("john");
        
        return repo.save(myEntity);
    }
}
```

Thanks in adavance!

Comment: Seems like transactions are not isolated (I in ACID properties). Try using and understanding `Isolation` parameter for `@Transactional` annotation. In your case, I would use `@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.READ_COMMITTED)`

Comment: Let me know the result!

Comment: Hi, tried your solution but didn't work. I guess in this case the transaction is one, the one created by the methodA, so no isolation should be involved.

Comment: Definitely there's two transactions, `methodB` is annotated by `@Transactional` and is invoked by `methodA` which is also annotated by `@Transactional`. Are you running this through multiple threads or a single thread?

Comment: I'm not handling threads manually, just using plain spring boot + spring data so I guess single thread. Anyway if I remove the annotation from methodB the outcome doesn't change, can't understand why!